# Access locally stored file in NodeJS/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I am looking to access the locally created PDF in the `server(NODEJS/Express)` side, i am fairly new to java script and haven't seen any method to access the file.
I think i can use something like `${__dirname}/${user_details.Invoice_No_latest}.pdf` but i am not sure if it is correct, any suggestions please

- As can seen below the PDF that is generated `(using html-pdf)` is getting saved locally in the folder D:\Programming\Repo\JavaScript-Project\ec-server\22.pdf'

[image]

- Once i get access to the file then i will use some thing similar as below code to save it to the database `MySql`

`Snippet` of code that i am looking to use afterwards

```
 var jsfile = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    var query = 'INSERT INTO `files` SET ?',
        values = {
          type: 'pdf',
          data: jsfile
        };
    mysql.query(query, values, function(err) {
      if (err) throw err; // TODO: improve
      // do something after successful insertion
    });
```

just looking if there is any simple way to access annd play with any file in the `nodejs/Express` that is stored locally there.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to use a locally stored file using the `fs.readFile(/* Arguments Here */)` function as shown here:

```js
fs.readFile(`${__dirname}\\` + `${Invoice_No_Actual}` + `.pdf`, (err, data) => {
  if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
  else {
    console.log(data);
    res.contentType("blob");
    res.send(`data:application/pdf;base64,${new Buffer.from(data).toString("base64")}`);
  }
});
```